# Why does slideToggle() open the span twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

http://jsfiddle.net/mBkM3/

Whenever I click the button, it opens twice and then closes.

Why doesn't it just alternate open and close with the proper .5 sec animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do it this way:

```
$(".add-entry").css('display','block').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mBkM3/3/

Comment: cool, thanks. Any reason it behaves this way in the first place?

Comment: Apparently inline elements behave strangely, but block elements transition correctly. I imagine this results from the fact that specifying a height for an inline element has no effect.

Comment: @davidchambers is right, inline elements havent a fixed height. So I added a CSS style to represent your span as block element. Also you can use <div/> instead of <span/> in this case there will be no need to use my CSS fix.